# How to receive data in ActionCable Channel without JS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm writing a Rails application that uses WebSockets to communicate with other machines (no browser and client side logic in this process). I have a channel:

```
class MachinesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    ...
  end

  def unsubscribed
    ...
  end

  def handle_messages
    ...
  end
end
```

To receive the data the only way I know about is the JavaScript client:

```
ActionCable.createConsumer('/cable').subscriptions.create 'MachinesChannel',
  received: (message) ->
    @perform('handle_messages')
```

I can call server side methods from JS via `@perform()` method.

Is there any way to omit the JS part and somehow directly handle the incoming data in `MachinesChannel`?

The ideal situation would be to have the `handle_messages` method accept a `data` argument and have this metod called on incoming data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into `ActionCable` source code I got the following solution. You just have to create a method in `MachinesChannel` that you want to be called, e.g. `handle_messages(data)`. Then, in the client that connects to your websocket, you need to send a message in the following format (example in ruby):

```
id = { channel: 'MachinesChannel' }
ws = WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect(url)
ws.send(JSON.generate(command: 'message', identifier: JSON.generate(id), data: JSON.generate(action: 'handle_messages', foo: 'bar', biz: 'baz')))
```

`action` has to be the name of the method you want to be called in `MachinesChannel`. The rest of key-values are whatever you want. This the date you can receive in the `ActionCable` channel.

Recently a gem [action_cable_client](https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/action_cable_client) has been release which seems exactly perfect for this kind of usage. I haven't used it, so I don't know how it really works.

Comment: hey! action_cable_client is my gem. if anybody has any questions on usage, I'm happy to help! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
def handle_messages
 ...
end
```

This works for me:

```
def receive(data)
  puts data
  ...
end
```